# In Entity Framework how do I configure a shadow owned entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In EF Core 3.1 I am attempting to implement a *Concurrency Token* for my base class.  I run into problems for entities stored in shared tables of which a derived class owns an entity.  When the derived class holds a single property, it is advised to create this property as a shadow property on the base class.  However with the property that represents an owned type I don't know how I can do this.  I am trying to avoid putting in a shadow property for every single property in the owned type.

The class from which all entities are derived:

```c
public class EntityClass
{
    ///...
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] ConcurrencyToken { get; set; }
}
```

An example of a base class and the derived class that holds an additional owned type:

```c
public class Transaction : EntityClass
{
    ///...
    public Company Counterparty { get; set; }
    public Currency TransactionCurrency { get; set; }
}
public class CashTransaction : Transaction
{
    ///...
    public Currency BankAccountCurrency { get; set; }
}
```

`Currency` is an owned model and its properties are stored in the table related to `Transaction`:

```c
[Owned, ComplexType]
public class Currency
{
    ///...
    public string CurrencyName { get; set; }
    public string CurrencySymbol { get; set; }
}
```

When I add the migration the following error shows:

> Entity type 'CashTransaction.BankAccountCurrency#Currency' doesn't contain a property mapped to the store-generated concurrency token column 'ConcurrencyToken' that is used by another entity type sharing the table 'Transaction'. Add a store-generated property mapped to the same column to 'CashTransaction.BankAccountCurrency#Currency'. It can be in shadow state.

I tried to configure the shadow property with a few tries, for example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>().OwnsOne<Currency>("BankAccountCurrency");
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Below does not work: it leads to issues with change tracking on derived class.

For a while I thought below would work: create a private property of the owned entity, and then configure this in the `modelBuilder` call:

```c
public class Transaction : EntityClass
{
    ///...
    public Company Counterparty { get; set; }
    public Currency TransactionCurrency { get; set; }
    private Currency BankAccountCurrency { get; set; }
}
```

```c
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>().OwnsOne(typeof(Currency), nameof(CashTransaction.BankAccountCurrency));
```